# Sending packets from a host to another host in a different subnet

Tags: networking, udp, scapy

I am currently doing some practice in python for sending (UDP) packets. I am fairly new at this so I have been trying to conceptually understand what is going on.

Basically I am trying to send a packet from Host1 -> Router -> Host3. From my research, I need to send an ARP request from Host1 to Router to get the Router MAC address, then I send an Ethernet frame to the router. From here I conceptually get kind of lost. The router looks up on its IP table to find Host2 in order to send the message? None the less this is what my code looks like at the moment.

I am also currently using a mininet router.py to simulate these hosts and routers.

```
port = 12345


def get_ip_address(ifname):
    ni.ifaddresses(ifname)
    ip = ni.ifaddresses(ifname)[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
    return ip


def sendArpMesage(interfaceName, dst_ip):
    #s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=dst_ip), timeout=2, iface=interfaceName, inter=0.2)

    for send, receive in ans:
        return(receive.sprintf(r"%Ether.src%"))


def get_netmask(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x891b, struct.pack('256s',ifname))[20:24])


def sendIPMessage(interfaceName, dst_ip, routerIP, message):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(("", port))

    src_addr = get_mac_address(interface=interfaceName)

    my_ip = get_ip_address(interfaceName)
    netmask = ipaddress.ip_address(dst_ip) in ipaddress.ip_network(my_ip)
    if netmask is True:  # if dst is in the same network
        arp_MAC = sendArpMesage(interfaceName, dst_ip)
    else:
        arp_MAC = sendArpMesage(interfaceName, routerIP)


    msg = message.encode('utf-8')
    packet = send(Ether(src=src_addr, dst=arp_MAC)/IP(src=my_ip, dst=dst_ip)/UDP(dport=port)/msg)
    #print(packet.show())
```

If print is uncommitted I receive the error

```
print(packet.show())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'
```

The output of running `sendIPMessage` is

```
Begin emission:
*Finished sending 1 packets.

Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
.
Sent 1 packets.
```

And wireshark shows the ARP request to the router and a malformed packet

[image]

Edit: When trying to show the contents of the packet, I realized I was in the wrong function. However now there seems to be a problem in the checksum of the packet.

Comment: For your code example, please make sure it's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), complete with all imports so it's easier to replicate.

Comment: "The router looks up on its IP table to find Host2 in order to send the message?", "Any help for getting the packet to send to a host on another subnet would be extremely appreciated." => What is your one question here? If you want to ARP between subnets, it's [not possible](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26163/do-broadcast-ffffffffffff-packets-go-through-the-router-or-directly-all).

Comment: @RossJacobs I'm not trying to send the ARP request between subnets, I successfully get the MAC address from the router, so I need to send a UDP package to the router and (heres where I conceptually don't understand) the router then gets the package to Host 2? It is this last step that I am confused about. Because everything works besides the `send(Ether(src=src_addr, dst=arp_MAC)/IP(src=my_ip, dst=dst_ip)/UDP(dport=port)/msg)`

Comment: "Because everything works besides the `send(Ether(src=src_addr, dst=arp_MAC)/IP(src=my_ip, dst=dst_ip)/UDP(dport=port)/msg)`" => sooooo this packet doesn't get sent? Isn't received by host3?

Comment: Right, wireshark Host1 does not show any packets being sent (besides the ARP to the router) and Host2 does not receive anything. There are no errors when I run the command either.

Comment: Add the results of `packet.show()` for this packet to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58708507/edit).

Comment: Okay, I am not on my linux machine at the moment, but I will add and tag you as soon as possible.

Comment: @RossJacobs I realized a couple mistakes and added a small edit section at the bottom. I added new information. At this time the packet does send a malformed packet but `pack.show()` is a NoneType object

Comment: Scapy isn't going to send the packet if `packet == None`.

Comment: I thought it was created correctly, but I will keep doing research. @RossJacobs